# Designating current delegate object

Tags: c#, delegates

For example with a scheduler class like this:

```
class Scheduler
{
    public void Add(DateTime time, Action action);
    ...
}
```

I can plan a simple action like this:

```
Scheduler scheduler= new Scheduler();
scheduler.Add(someTime, delegate() { Console.WriteLine("Done!"); });
```

Now I want my action to replan itself later, so I write this:

```
scheduler.Add(someTime, delegate() { Console.WriteLine("Done!"); scheduler.Add(someTimeLater, !this current action!); });
```

But how can I designate !this current action! or code this in another way?

Comment: how can you reference the delegate before its added? Even assuming that `Scheduler` exposes the delegates in some way. Should't your signature be `public void Add(DateTime time, Action<Scheduler> action)`?

Comment: @Jodrell by putting it into a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to assign it to a variable to do this:

```
Action action = null;
action = () => 
{
    Console.WriteLine("Done!"); 
    scheduler.Add(someTimeLater, action);
};
scheduler.Add(someTime, action);
```